# Django Cookie Prefix to pass securityheaders.com

Tags: django, security, cookies

securityheaders.com fails my configurations with the following error:

```
Set-Cookie  There is no Cookie Prefix on this cookie.
```

And this is the value of the cookie:

```
Set-Cookie  sessionid=123456789123456789123456789; expires=Thu, 12 Sep 2019 06:51:38 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure
```

I have tried to add the cookie prefix with in settings.py:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = '__Secure-csrftoken'
```

But it seems to be a different paramater. I have search the documentation and that is all I could find, and seems to not be applicable.

[securityheaders.com on cookie prefixes](https://scotthelme.co.uk/tough-cookies/) states that it needs to start with `__Secure-` or `__Host-`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You used the wrong setting, this is *not* the [**`CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-name), but the [**`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name):

> Default: **`'sessionid'`**
>
> The name of the **cookie to use for sessions**. This can be whatever you want (as long as it’s different from the other cookie names in your application).

Note that the name of the cookie it complains about is `sessionid`:

```
Set-Cookie  sessionid=123456789123456789123456789; expires=Thu, 12 Sep 2019 06:51:38 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure
```

So you need to specify this as:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = '__Secure-sessionid'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = '__Secure-csrftoken'
```